# is possible write/read a file using a string data type structure?

Tags: delphi, file, delphi-xe2

for write something in a file i use for example this code:

```
procedure MyProc (... );
const
  BufSize = 65535;
var
  FileSrc, FileDst: TFileStream;
  StreamRead: Cardinal;
  InBuf, OutBuf: Array [0..bufsize] of byte;
begin
  .....
  FileSrc := TFileStream.Create (uFileSrc, fmOpenRead Or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    FileDst := TFileStream.Create (uFileTmp, fmCreate);
    try
      StreamRead := 0;
      while ((iCounter < iFileSize) or (StreamRead = Cardinal(BufSize))) 
      begin
        StreamRead := FileSrc.Read (InBuf, BufSize);
        Inc (iCounter, StreamRead);
      end;
    finally
      FileDst.Free;
    end;
  finally
    FileSrc.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And for I/O file i use a array of byte, and so is all ok, but when i use a string, for example declaring:

```
InBuf, OutBuf: string  // in delphi xe2 = unicode string
```

then not work. In sense that file not write nothing. I have understood why, or just think to have understood it.
I think that problem maybe is why string contain just a pointer to memory and not static structure; correct? 
In this case, there is some solution for solve it? In sense, is possible to do something for i can to write a file using string and not vector? Or i need necessary use a vector? 
If possible, can i can to do ?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Why use a string? The stack allocated byte buffer looks good to me.

Comment: In effect, is so; sincerly data are in string unicode and i need to do operation on it. just was for not to do much conversion from string unicode to array of byte, and semplify so the code. Other reason is that i wanted to have "bufsize" variable and not static in a class. Too when i use dynamic array and set lenght of it, i have same problem.

Comment: What exactly *is* the problem? Am I right in assuming that you don't just copy data from one file to another? You do some processing before you write the data out again, right?

Comment: eew, systems hungarian notation in Pascal... read string character-by-character, cease reading when #0 encountered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with using strings. First of all you want to use `RawByteString` so that you ensure the use of byte sized character elements – a Unicode string has elements that are two bytes wide. And secondly you need to dereference the string which is really just a pointer.

But I wonder why you would prefer strings to the stack allocated byte array.

```
procedure MyProc (... );
const
  BufSize = 65536;
var
  FileSrc, FileDst: TFileStream;
  StreamRead: Cardinal;
  InBuf: RawByteString;
begin
  .....
  FileSrc := TFileStream.Create (uFileSrc, fmOpenRead Or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    FileDst := TFileStream.Create (uFileTmp, fmCreate);
    try
      SetLength(InBuf, BufSize);
      StreamRead := 0;
      while ((iCounter < iFileSize) or (StreamRead = Cardinal(BufSize))) 
      begin
        StreamRead := FileSrc.Read (InBuf[1], BufSize);
        Inc (iCounter, StreamRead);
      end;
    finally
      FileDst.Free;
    end;
  finally
    FileSrc.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**Note:** Your previous code declared a buffer of 65536 bytes, but you only ever used 65535 of them. Probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 3):

To use a string as a buffer (which I would not recommend), you'll have to use SetLength to allocate the internal buffer, and you'll have to pass InBuf[1] and OutBuf[1] as the data to read or write.

```
  var
    InBuf, OutBuf: AnsiString; // or TBytes
  begin
    SetLength(InBuf, BufSize);
    SetLength(OutBuf, BufSize);

    ...

    StreamRead := FileSrc.Read(InBuf[1], BufSize); // if TBytes, use InBuf[0]

    // etc...
```

You can also use a TBytes, instead of an AnsiString. The usage remains the same.

**But I actually see no advantage in dynamically allocating TBytes, AnsiStrings or RawByteStrings here**. I'd rather do what you already do: use a stack based buffer. I would perhaps make it a little smaller in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: Yes, i have tried too this solution, but was same problem. :( maybe becouse he see a pointer only?

Comment: "but was same problem" You haven't given any details as to what that problem was. Are we to guess?

Comment: @Rudy Why make the buffer smaller in a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: @David: Just a gut feeling. No rational explanation, sorry.

Comment: @Marcello: What problem? What do you mean with the second sentence?

Comment: @rudy, i tell about string and dynamic array

Comment: @Marcello: from what you wrote, I can't tell what your problem is. I assume you want to load the data as unicode string, but then you'll have to do it differently, especially if the file is not unicode. Why don't you use a TStringList, load the file, modify the text and then write it out again? TStringList will take care of the details for you.

Comment: Yes, but i need work in unicode string, becouse i need manage binary file.

Comment: @Marcello: that doesn't make sense. If the file is binary, why do you need unicode strings?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save / load strings to / from stream, see the following example

```
var Len: Integer;
    buf: string;
    FData: TStream;

// save string to stream
// save the length of the string
Len := Length(buf);
FData.Write(Len, SizeOf(Len));
// save string itself
if(Len > 0)then FData.Write(buf[1], Len * sizeof(buf[1]));

// read string from stream
// read the length of the string
FData.Read(Len, SizeOf(Len));
if(Len > 0)then begin
   // get memory for the string
   SetLength(buf, Len);
   // read string content
   FData.Read(buf[1], Len * sizeof(buf[1]));
end else buf := '';
```

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, to copy the contents from one `TStream` to another `TStream`, you could just use the `TStream.CopyFrom()` method instead:

```
procedure MyProc (... );
var
  FileSrc, FileDst: TFileStream;
begin
  ...
  FileSrc := TFileStream.Create (uFileSrc, fmOpenRead Or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    FileDst := TFileStream.Create (uFileTmp, fmCreate);
    try
      FileDst.CopyFrom(FileSrc, 0); // or FileDst.CopyFrom(FileSrc, iFileSize)
    finally
      FileDst.Free;
    end;
  finally
    FileSrc.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Which can be simplified by calling CopyFile() instead:

```
procedure MyProc (... );
begin
  ...
  CopyFile(PChar(uFileSrc), PChar(uFileTmp), False);
  ...
end;
```

Either way, you don't have to worry about read/writing the file data manually at all!

Comment: This solution is very good and i will use it when need copy file directy, but in my case after that i have read data from file source, i need to do operation on it and then write it after in  destination file.

Comment: In that case, you really should use `TBytes` or `array of byte` instead of any `String` type to hold the file data.  Strings are NOT suitable binary containers, especially in D2009+.